# Persistence provider error after updating to spring boot 3

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

My application always fail on runtime only, after updating to spring boot 3.0.0.
I try to run the application with developpement properties on my local machine.
I use gradle 7.6, and Java 17.0.4.

```
2022-12-11T23:21:54.136+01:00  WARN 17936 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
2022-12-11T23:21:54.142+01:00  INFO 17936 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-12-11T23:21:54.171+01:00  INFO 17936 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-12-11T23:21:54.202+01:00 ERROR 17936 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1130) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:905) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at com.muqel.api.MuqelApi.main(MuqelApi.java:30) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
```

Used application properties :

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

application-dev.yml

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: "dev"
  datasource:
#    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/muqel_db?user=postgres&password=admin
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/muqel_db
    username: postgres
    password: admin
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
  jackson:
    serialization:
      fail-on-empty-beans: false

server:
  port: 8889
```